# Display date in dd/mm/yyyy format in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datetime-format

I want to display date in 09/07/2013 format instead of 09-jul-13.

```
Dim dt As Date = Date.Today

MsgBox(dt)
```

Comment: [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

First, uppercase MM are months and lowercase mm are minutes.

You have to pass `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` to `ToString` to ensure that `/` as date separator is used since it would normally be replaced with the current culture's date separator:

```
MsgBox(dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
```

Another option is to escape that custom format specifier by embedding the / within ':

```
dt.ToString("dd'/'MM'/'yyyy")
```

[**MSDN**: The "/" Custom Format Specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#dateSeparator):

> The "/" custom format specifier represents the date separator, which
>   is used to differentiate years, months, and days. The appropriate
>   localized date separator is retrieved from the
>   `DateTimeFormatInfo.DateSeparator` property **of the current** or specified
>   **culture**.

Comment: that is why i like PHP,I am a PHP programmer and learning VB.Net. in PHP just use echo date("d/m/y"); thats all.

Comment: @Ravikant: I assume it's looks more complicated in .NET because it's  more powerful. So you can change the format easily or even change the language of the month names, e.g.: `dt.ToString("dd/MMMM yyyy, dddd")`

Comment: @Ravikant: You can also use `dt.ToShortDateString()` or `dt.ToString("d")`. A `DateTime` contains the time, that's why you need to apply a format string (or use the `Date`-method) to get only the date part.

Comment: Thanks for your support. Finally i have added System.Globalization namespace and it is working now.

Comment: @Ravikant Or you can try another answer, there are very simple ones

Answer (score 11):

Try this.

```
 var dateAsString = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
// dateAsString = "09/07/2013"
```

and also [check this link for more formatting data and time](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)

Answer (score 4):

Like this ..

```
MsgBox(format(dt,"dd/MM/yyyy"))
```

Comment: i already have tried it, it displays 09-00-2013. I have also tried tostring("dd/mm/yyyy") but not working.

Comment: It should be "dd/MM/yyyy". `mm` is for minutes and `MM` for month.

Answer (score 2):

You could decompose the date into it's constituent parts and then concatenate them together like this:

```
MsgBox(Now.Day & "/" & Now.Month & "/" & Now.Year)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim formattedDate As String = Date.Today.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
```

[Check link below](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28VS.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I found this catered for dates in 21st Century that could be entered as dd/mm or dd/mm/yy.  It is intended to print an attendance register and asks for the meeting date to start with.

```
Sub Print_Register()

Dim MeetingDate, Answer

    Sheets("Register").Select
    Range("A1").Select
GetDate:
    MeetingDate = DateValue(InputBox("Enter the date of the meeting." & Chr(13) & _
    "Note Format" & Chr(13) & "Format DD/MM/YY or DD/MM", "Meeting Date", , 10000, 10000))
    If MeetingDate = "" Then GoTo TheEnd
    If MeetingDate < 36526 Then MeetingDate = MeetingDate + 36526
    Range("Current_Meeting_Date") = MeetingDate
    Answer = MsgBox("Date OK?", 3)
    If Answer = 2 Then GoTo TheEnd
    If Answer = 7 Then GoTo GetDate
    ExecuteExcel4Macro "PRINT(1,,,1,,,,,,,,2,,,TRUE,,FALSE)"
TheEnd:
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to display date along with time when you export to Excel then you can use this

```
xlWorkSheet.Cells(nRow, 3).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yy h:mm AM/PM"
```