# Vb. NET Convert a date to number

Tags: vb.net

I have this code in VB . NET

```
dim date_e As DateTime
date_e = New DateTime(CLng(Convert.ToDouble("635434240520170000")))
```

The result is:

```
12.08.2014 07:07:32
```

Now my question is how i can reverse that encoding to obtain the number from a specific date and time witch i input myself:
Lets' say.

```
22.09.2014 07:07:32
```

Thank you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17546184/display-date-in-dd-mm-yyyy-format-in-vb-net

Comment: Instead of converting the string to a double and then to a long. Just convert it directly to a long with Convert.ToInt64("635434240520170000")

Answer (score 4):

The [`DateTime` constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2xf7zzk(v=vs.110).aspx) that takes a `Long` are the ticks since January 1, 0001 at 00:00:00.000 in the Gregorian calendar.

You just need to parse the string to `Date` first, then you can use it's [`Ticks` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Dim dt = Date.Parse("22.09.2014 07:07:32") ' presumes that this is the correct format
Dim ticks As Long = dt.Ticks
```

If the input date-string is in a different format than your current culture you can use `Date.Parse` with the correct culture:

```
dt = Date.Parse("22.09.2014 07:07:32", New CultureInfo("de-DE"))
```

or - if you don't know the culture but only the format - `Date.ParseExact`:

```
dt = Date.ParseExact("22.09.2014 07:07:32", "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```