# How to sum up all the datetime/time in a datagridview vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net

I've been wondering how can I convert this line of code which compute the sum of an integer.

I need to sum up all my column data from the datagridview which is in a timespan format(0,0,0)

I'm getting an error

> System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'

any help?

```
txtTotalTime.Text = 
 ( From row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView3.Rows
   Where row.Cells(2).FormattedValue.ToString() <> String.Empty
   Select Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells(2).FormattedValue)
 ).Sum().ToString()
```

Comment: also tried this code but i cant convert it -------------------Dim sum As Integer = 0
        For i As Integer = 0 To dataGridView1.Rows.Count() - 1 Step +1
            sum = sum + dataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value
        Next

        textBoxSum.Text = sum.ToString()

Comment: Perhaps try with `Date.Parse` (Ex: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25010823/vb-net-convert-a-date-to-number)

Comment: this didnt worked for me. is  there another way how to compute for the sum of datetime

for example i just need to sum up all the datetime from my datagridview column (with this format 08:42:32)

Comment: Can you update the post with some sample data? Are you just trying to sum the time component (not date)?

Comment: a string like "08:42:32" is not going to be directly convertible to integer obviously. Which value do you want to sum? Hours, minutes, seconds?

Comment: What's the good format? You said `(0,0,0)`. Is it `hh,mm,ss` or `hh:mm:ss`?

Comment: show some real examples of the columns. Preferrably, we'd see both `Value` and `FormattedValue` properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this helps (just another way to do it). It is along the same lines of Amessihel.

NOTE: if TimeOfDay is greater than 24 hrs. then it puts out EX: "1.00:05:09"

```
        Dim dgvrRow As DataGridViewRow  
        Dim tsSum As TimeSpan  
        Dim tsTemp As TimeSpan          

        TimeSpan.TryParse("00:00:00", tsSum) 

        For Each row In datagridview3.rows  
            strTemp = row.Cells(2).Value.ToString  
            If strTemp <> String.Empty Then  
                tsTemp = DateTime.ParseExact(strTemp, "HH,mm,ss", Nothing).TimeOfDay  

                tsSum = tsSum.Add(tsTemp)  
            End If  
        Next  

        txtTotalTime.Text = tsSum.toString
```

Comment: same does with this line of codes it says 'String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.'

Comment: then, change the format in the ParseExact statement to the one you are expecting. EX:   "HH,mm,ss" -->  "HH:mm:ss"

Comment: If you liked one of our posts then, please accept as answer and Upvote them. Thx.

Comment: how to do that? sorry i just created this account yesterday

Comment: Well, glad your answer is accepted by OP. :) I'm still wondering why @FredLorenz wrote `format(0,0,0)`.

Answer (score 0):

[Unfortunately](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4703056/4375327), **`Sum()`** cannot handle a **set** of **`TimeSpan`**. So the trick here is:

1. To parse each entry invoking `DateTime.ParseExact` with a custom format (I assumed yours was `h,m,s`)
2. To convert them as "Ticks", a `Long` value.
3. To pass the Long values to `Sum()`
4. And finally to convert the result as a TimeSpan.

Below a working piece of code:

```
Dim ts As TimeSpan = New TimeSpan(
        (From row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView3.Rows
         Where row.Cells(2).FormattedValue.ToString() <> String.Empty
         Select DateTime.ParseExact(row.Cells(2).FormattedValue, "h,m,s", Nothing).TimeOfDay.Ticks
             ).Sum())
txtTotalTime.Text = ts.ToString
```

Note: `Nothing` is passed here as a *format provider*. `Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` could also be passed with the same effect.

Comment: i am encoutering an error it says 'String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.'

Comment: What is the format you used ? In your question it was like `h,m,s`.