# Issue with Custom Date Format in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

Good day everyone!

I have a problem about custom date format in VB.NET and I already tried to use these codes:

- [Display date in dd/mm/yyyy format in vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17546333/7514462)
- [VB.NET DateTime Format Functions - Dot Net Perls](https://www.dotnetperls.com/datetime-format-vbnet)

but none of them are working for me.

First, this the source code where I get the first and last day of the month

- [Get the first/last day of the month with VB.NET](https://begeeben.wordpress.com/2012/05/03/get-the-firstlast-day-of-the-month-with-vb-net/)

Code:

```
Public Function FirstDayOfMonth(ByVal sourceDate As DateTime) As DateTime    
    Return New DateTime(sourceDate.Year, sourceDate.Month, 1)
End Function

Public Function LastDayOfMonth(ByVal sourceDate As DateTime) As DateTime
    Dim lastDay As DateTime = New DateTime(sourceDate.Year, sourceDate.Month, 1)
    Return lastDay.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1)
End Function
```

This is the output

```
3/1/2018 & 3/31/2018
```

Example:

**My first attempt based on Source# 1**

```
Dim startDayMonth As String
Dim endDayMonth As String

startDayMonth = startDayMonth.ToString("dd")
endDayMonth = endDayMonth.ToString("dd")

MsgBox(startDayMonth & " " & endDayMonth)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in TIMELOG.exe

Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.IFormatProvider'.
```

**My second attempt based on Source# 2**

```
Dim startDayMonth As DateTime
Dim endDayMonth As DateTime
Dim dateFormat As String

dateFormat = "%d"

startDayMonth = FirstDayOfMonth(Now)
endDayMonth = LastDayOfMonth(Now)

startDayMonth = startDayMonth.ToString(dateFormat)
endDayMonth = endDayMonth.ToString(dateFormat)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll

Additional information: Conversion from string "1" to type 'Date' is not valid.
```

**Own Method #1**

```
Dim startDayMonth As DateTime
Dim endDayMonth As DateTime
Dim dateFormat As String

dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

startDayMonth = Convert.ToString(FirstDayOfMonth(Now))
endDayMonth = Convert.ToString(LastDayOfMonth(Now))

startDayMonth = startDayMonth.ToString(dateFormat)
endDayMonth = endDayMonth.ToString(dateFormat)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
3/1/2018 3/31/2018
```

**Own Method #2**

```
Dim startDayMonth As DateTime
Dim endDayMonth As DateTime
Dim dateFormat As String

dateFormat = "%yyyy-MM-dd"

startDayMonth = Convert.ToString(FirstDayOfMonth(Now))
endDayMonth = Convert.ToString(LastDayOfMonth(Now))

startDayMonth = startDayMonth.ToString(dateFormat)
endDayMonth = endDayMonth.ToString(dateFormat)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll

Additional information: Conversion from string "182018-03-01" to type 'Date' is not valid.
```

Comment: What does "not working for me" mean?

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense. In the last block you declare `startDayMonth` as a `DateTime`, but then you try to assign a `string` to it (`startDayMonth = Convert.ToString(FirstDayOfMonth(Now))`). Have you got `Option Strict` turned on for your code? If not, turn that on and then revise  your question.

Comment: @Enigmativityplease see the output in every attempt and own method. Thanks

Comment: In most of those code snippets, you have declared `startDayMonth` and `endDayMonth` as type `DateTime` and then gone ahead and assigned `String` objects to them. How does it make sense to call `ToString` and assign the result a variable that is not type `String`? Start by turning `Option Strict On` and fix all the issues with data types first, then you might have a chance of writing code that does something sensible.

Comment: I get it now! Sorry I forgot to declare another `String`.. and now it's working fine :-) thanks for the enlightenment

Answer (score 0):

Pay better attention to what data types you are using in what situations. Strings are not DateTime values, and DateTime values are not strings. You need variables declared with the correct type to hold each kind of value.

The `FirstDayOfMonth()` and `LastDayOfMonth()` functions use `DateTime` values. This is good. However, `DateTime` values ***always*** use a binary format for their data which is not human readable. You cannot change this, but that's okay; you can easily convert the values to *strings* formatted however you want. You just need to use *different* variables to store the string values that are declared to use the `string` type:

```
Dim format As String = "%d"
Dim startDayMonth As DateTime = FirstDayOfMonth(Now)
Dim endDayMonth As DateTime = LastDayOfMonth(Now)
Dim startDayMonthFormatted As String = startDayMonth.ToString(format)
Dim lastDayMonthFormatted As String = lastDayMonth.ToString(format)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set `Option Strict On` **always, 100% of the time** when coding in VB.NET.

### Source #1

```
startDayMonth = startDayMonth.ToString("dd")
endDayMonth = endDayMonth.ToString("dd")
```

I get a **compile-time error**:

> BC30512 Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'String' to 'IFormatProvider'.

Without `Option Strict On` I get a **run-time error**:

> InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.IFormatProvider'.

Compile-time errors are infinitely better than run-time errors. It's impossible to deploy compile-time errors to customers.

### Source #2

```
startDayMonth = startDayMonth.ToString(dateFormat)
endDayMonth = endDayMonth.ToString(dateFormat)
```

> BC30512 Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'String' to 'Date'.

The same applies with **own method #1** and **own method #2**.

You would not have even asked this question had you have `Option Strict On`.

Please turn it on. Then your compiler can tell you where you are going wrong.