# Data return is NULL even tho I have a value on my SQL in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

Good day this is the continuation on my previous question since it's already been solved.

- [Issue with Custom Date Format in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49164165/7514462)

Now the problem is WHEN I test my SQL query in phpMyAdmin returned a value

[image]

it means that the `rd.GetString(0)` has a value of "3"

But when the vb.net load the value, it will return an error:

```
Additional information: Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.
```

Why is the Data is NULL but on my SQL screenshot is working fine?

this is the error that refer to

```
If Convert.ToDouble(rd.GetString(0)) >= 80.0 Then
```

or I use this

```
If  rd.GetDecimal(0) >= 80.0 Then
```

same result

My entire code:

```
    Dim startDayMonth As DateTime = FirstDayOfMonth(Now).AddHours(6)
    Dim lastDayMonth As DateTime = LastDayOfMonth(Now).AddHours(22)

    Dim qry As String = "SELECT SUM(totalWorkHour) as totalWorkHour FROM tbltimesheet WHERE studInfoID=@id " _
        & "AND timeIn BETWEEN @checkAM AND @checkPM"

    Using con As New MySqlConnection("server=192.168.*.***; user=dummyUsername; password=dummyPasswrd; database=dummyDBName;"), _
        cmd As New MySqlCommand(qry, con)

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = Convert.ToInt32(Me.txtStudID.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@checkAM", MySqlDbType.DateTime).Value = startDayMonth
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@checkPM", MySqlDbType.DateTime).Value = lastDayMonth
        con.Open()

        Using rd As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            'Better practice here would be to return the value (if any) from this function
            If rd.Read() Then
                If rd.GetDecimal(0) >= 80.0 Then
                    MsgBox("Hurray! You already reach your target: " & rd.GetString(0), MsgBoxStyle.Information, Title:="Result")
                Else
                    MsgBox("Your Total Work Hour: " & rd.GetString(0), MsgBoxStyle.Information, Title:="Result")
                End If
            Else
                MsgBox("No Record Found", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, Title:="Error")
            End If
        End Using
    End Using

    rd.Close()
    con.Close()
```

Comment: Please don't post images of code.

Comment: I post the sql query on the `My entire code:` section.. I just want to show that the query is working fine

Comment: Try `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Convert.ToInt32(Me.txtStudID.Text))`, etc.

Comment: Why are you calling `GetString` in the first place?  If the value is a number to begin with, why get a `String` and then convert it to a number?  Why not just get a number?  Also, if you only want to get one value then call `ExecuteScalar` rather than use a data reader.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I'll try to search for the executescalar.. thanks for the reply

Comment: Also, If you're formatting datetime strings for a database query, you've completely misunderstood the point of query parameters. Just craft the DateTime values, and use those for the query parameters.

Comment: You really need to get a proper understanding of data types.  If you're trying to pass date/time values as ADO.NET parameters then DO NOT use `Strings`.  Use `DateTime` values. `startDayMonth` and `lastDayMonth` are `DateTime` values.  That's what you want.  If you want to add times then call their `AddHours` methods and then use those results as your parameter values please THINK about your data types.  Don't just use `Strings` everywhere.  `Strings` are a specific thing, not a general hold-all.  If something is not text then it's not a `String`.

Comment: how can I craft the DateTime values that will start from 6Am and it will end to 11PM? based on my query I want to compute the totalWorkHour from the day 1 of the month to the last day of the month with between 6am to 11pm? the solution that I think of is that get the date automatically and put a static for the time.. I search in the internet but I can't find the right code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of small fixes in here:

```vb
'Just leave these as a datetime
Dim StartDayMonth As DateTime = FirstDayOfMonth(Now).AddHours(6)
Dim LastDayMonth As DateTime = LastDayOfMonth(Now).AddHours(22)

Dim qry As String = _
    "SELECT SUM(totalWorkHour) as totalWorkHour " & _ 
    " FROM tbltimesheet " & _
    " WHERE studInfoID=@id AND timeIn BETWEEN @checkAM AND @checkPM"

'.Net uses Connection Pooling for database objects...
'    This means create a new connection for every query in most cases
'    but limit the scope and duration of the connection as much as possible
'    (wait until the last possible moment to call .Open())
Using con As New MySqlConnection("connection string here"), _
      cmd As New MySqlCommand(qry, con)

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value =  Convert.ToInt32(Me.txtStudID.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@checkAM", MySqlDbType.DateTime).Value = StartDayMonth
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@checkPM", MySqlDbType.DateTime).Value = LastDayMonth
    con.Open()

    Using rd As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        'Better practice here would be to return the value (if any) from this function
        If rd.Read()
            Dim hours As Double = rd.GetDouble(0)
            If hours >= 80.0 Then
                MsgBox("Hurray! You already reach your target: " & hours.ToString(), MsgBoxStyle.Information, Title:="Result")
            Else
                MsgBox("Your Total Work Hour: " & hours.ToString(), MsgBoxStyle.Information, Title:="Result")
            End If
        Else 
            MsgBox("No Record Found", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, Title:="Error")
        End If
    End Using
End Using
```

---

Now that I can also see the module, you want code more like this:

```
Module db
    'Note that this is PRIVATE
    '  Goal is to make sure any db access in your code really
    '  does use the interface provided by your db module.
    Private ConnectionString As String  = "server=192.168.*.***; user=******; password=*****; database=dbsalog;"

    'Note the use of types here in the function definition.
    'Also note how I separate concerns here:
    '   Limit functions in this Module to just database access doing database things
    '   Let your presentation code in your form worry about MsgBox() and other concerns
    Public Function GetWorkHours(StudentId As Integer) As Double
        Dim StartDayMonth As DateTime = FirstDayOfMonth(Now).AddHours(6)
        Dim LastDayMonth As DateTime = LastDayOfMonth(Now).AddHours(22)
        Dim qry As String = _
            "SELECT SUM(totalWorkHour) as totalWorkHour " & _ 
            " FROM tbltimesheet " & _
            " WHERE studInfoID=@id AND timeIn BETWEEN @checkAM AND @checkPM"

        Using con As New MySqlConnection(ConnectionString), _
              cmd As New MySqlCommand(qry, con)

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = StudentId
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@checkAM", MySqlDbType.DateTime).Value = StartDayMonth
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@checkPM", MySqlDbType.DateTime).Value = LastDayMonth
            con.Open()

            Using rd As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                If rd.Read() Return rd.GetDouble(0) 
            End Using
        End Using
        Return Nothing
    End Function
End Module
```

Which you can call from a form or other area of your program like this:

```
Dim workHours As Double = db.GetWorkHours(Convert.ToInt32(Me.txtStudId.Text))
If workHours = Nothing Then
    MsgBox("No Record Found", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, Title:="Error")
ElseIf workHours >= 80.0 Then
    MsgBox("Hurray! You already reach your target: " & workHours.ToString(), MsgBoxStyle.Information, Title:="Result")
Else
    MsgBox("Your Total Work Hour: " & workHours.ToString(), MsgBoxStyle.Information, Title:="Result")
End If
```

Comment: what do you mean by connection string? my host, username, password and name of the database? I already declare on my code.. I just forgot to include on my post.. I'll update my post

Comment: I already update the code.. I tried using yours but still Data is NULL

Comment: That's exactly what I mean. In .Net, it's **not good** to store the connection object at the module level like that. You want a new connection object each time you run a query. _Really._ Also... that `connectDB()` function is declared to return a string, but doesn't actually return anything. That's the kind of n00b mistake that has frustrated so many commenters on this question. If you can't get that kind of detail right, you will struggle as a programmer.

Comment: thanks for the heads up! I will follow your code... but the problem is  still the same... Data is Null on this part `Convert.ToDouble(rd.GetString(0)) >= 80.0 Then` I change it to `If rd.GetDecimal(0) >= 80.0 Then` since the structure in the database is `double` so I use `rd.GetDecimal(0)` by the way I just comment my `connectDB()` when I used your sample code

Comment: The `Data` in your error messages refers to a name somewhere in the code. But that name doesn't appear anywhere in the code you posted. That means we're missing something important that needs to be added to the question. My best guess is an exception is thrown, but you have a try/catch somewhere that's hiding it.

Comment: I update again my code... I fully converted my code to yours.. please check again.. thanks for sticking with me... UPDATE: oops! you updated your code... I will also update mine and I will get back to you soon

Comment: I'm back... same error... `Dim hours As Double = rd.GetDouble(0)` this line of code retrun in error report

Comment: I think I know why your code is not working... when I put the `startDayMonth` on the `MsgBox` this is the result: `3/1/2018 6:00:00 AM` since that is not the format on the MySQL database... I will convert first to this format: `2018-03-01 06:00:00` and I will update you again

Comment: **NOOOOO** If you're formating a datetime string for the database, you missed the point of parameterized queries. `DateTime` values do not have a human-readable format at all. You only see `3/1/2018 6:00:00 AM` because the debugger is nice and shows it to you that way. .Net has **binary** internal representation for DateTime values, and will convert it for use with MySql automatically to MySql's own internal format. No string value for that datetime object every exists.

Comment: as I refreshed the browser I saw your reply.. I didn't continue to convert the format... but still Data is Null and as your can see on my code is almost Identical to yours except for the new update: `Dim hours As Double = rd.GetDouble(0)`

Comment: @Mark I added a section that shows a better structure for the module.

Comment: yup! notice the changes.. I will get back to your once I finished my lunch.. it's already past 12 here... super thank you for sticking with me... I love the way you code.. that's the code I want on my vb project but didn't find on other source

Comment: It's getting close to bed time in my timezone. You'll likely be on  your own when you get back. Time to debug... step through one line at a time with Visual Studio and make sure all of the variable have the value you think they do.

Comment: I'm Back and I hope you are still awake... I already convert the code to yours and add a try & catch and still the error is `Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.`. Are you sure that VB.NET will convert the date provided: `3/1/2018 06:00:00 AM` to my database format which is `2018-03-01 06:00:00`?

Comment: at last problem SOLVE! thanks @Joel Coehoom.. I FORGOT that I'm inputting the studentID# not the ID of the student...